# ¿Cómo coger el resultado de dos declaraciones con JSON y devolverlo?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, if, backend

pues resulta que llevo ya 3 días como loco buscando sin parar y de probar mil cosas a ver si me funcionan, pero nada. La cosa, es que envío con JQuery Ajax dos valores data.

**Codigo JQuery :**

```
var dia_em = $(this).val();
$('.form_input_dias').val(dia_em);

var dia_em2 = $('.form_input_dias').val();

$.ajax({ 
    url:"backend.php",  
    method:"GET",
    data:{dia_id:dia_em, dia_id2:dia_em2},  
    success:function(data){ 
        $('.bxslider1').html(data[0]); 
        $('.bxslider2').html(data[1]); 

    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    },
});
```

Al enviar solo un valor y existir solo una función, al devolverlo con:  "$('.bxslider1').html(data);" funciona bien y no necesito json, pero al hacerlo con dos variables que devuelven 2 valores distintos a diferentes contenedores, me mezcla el contenido que supongo que es normal.

**backend.php**

```
  $get_dia_sel = request_var('dia_id', '0');
  $get_dia_sel2 = request_var('dia_id2', '0');

  if(isset($get_dia_sel)) {

      $link = mysqli_connect....;
      mysqli_select_db....;

      $query = "SELECT....";

      if($get_dia_selected == '0'){

         $query_contenido = "SELECT...."; 
         $query_count_contenido =   "SELECT ....";
      }

      $result_query = ....;
      $result_contenido = ....;

      $result_count_contenido = ....;
      $row_contador = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_count_contenido);
      $count_contenido = $row_contador['c'];

      if ($count_contenido < 8){

          foreach ($result_contenido as $row_contenido) { 
                  echo "<li><a><span>".$row_contenido['contenido']."</span><h5>".$row_contenido['nombre']."</h5></a></li>";
          }

          foreach ($result_query as $row_query) { 
            for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
                  echo "<li><a><span>".$row_query['contenido']."</span><h5>".$row_query['nombre']."</h5></a></li>";
          }
      } 
 }

 if(isset($get_dia_sel2)) {.......(el patrón de contenido es el mismo).............}
```

Quiero coger el resultado que salga del `IF "$get_dia_sel`" y del `$get_dia_sel2` y devolverlos de manera separada como se ve en el codigo JQuery.

He probado hacerlo con JSON pero no lo consigo, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, estoy desesperado ya, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te doy una posible solución, no la verifiqué porque no tengo el código completo pero es algo así:

**backend.php**

```
  if(isset($get_dia_sel)) {

      $link = mysqli_connect....;
      mysqli_select_db....;

      $query = "SELECT....";

      if($get_dia_selected == '0'){

         $query_contenido = "SELECT...."; 
         $query_count_contenido =   "SELECT ....";
      }

      $result_query = ....;
      $result_contenido = ....;

      $result_count_contenido = ....;
      $row_contador = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_count_contenido);
      $count_contenido = $row_contador['c'];

      $retorno = array();
      $retorno[0] = "";
      $retorno[1] = "";

      if ($count_contenido < 8){

          foreach ($result_contenido as $row_contenido) { 
                  $retorno[0].= "<li><a><span>".$row_contenido['contenido']."</span><h5>".$row_contenido['nombre']."</h5></a></li>";
          }

          foreach ($result_query as $row_query) { 
            for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
                  $retorno[0].= "<li><a><span>".$row_query['contenido']."</span><h5>".$row_query['nombre']."</h5></a></li>";
          }
      } 
 }

 if(isset($get_dia_sel2)) {.......(el patrón de contenido es el mismo).............}
$retorno[1].= .......(el patrón de contenido es el mismo).............
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

**Código Jquery**

```
var dia_em = $(this).val();
$('.form_input_dias').val(dia_em);

var dia_em2 = $('.form_input_dias').val();

$.ajax({ 
    url:"backend.php",  
    method:"GET",
    data:{dia_id:dia_em, dia_id2:dia_em2},  
    success:function(data){ 
    var data_parse = JSON.parse(data);
        $('.bxslider1').html(data_parse[0]); 
        $('.bxslider2').html(data_parse[1]); 

    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    },
});
```

Espero que comprendas la solución, la idea es guardar el echo que antes se realizaba en un array y después manipular ese array desde javascript.
Cualquier duda, comentame.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no ha funcionado :( ya lo había probado de esa forma aunque declarando las variables fuera ya que si quiero que afecte a ambas declaraciones independientes de IFs es como lo tendría que hacer, aunque lo he probado por si acaso dentro y lógicamente no ha funcionado tampoco. Si para solucionarlo necesitas todo el código no me importa pasártelo XD simplemente quiero solucionarlo lo antes posible.

Comment: Al final era problema del Bxslider, gracias por intentar ayudar.

Comment: Una pregunta más si no te molesta, y espero que lo veas. Resulta que también utilizo la transmisión de datos con ajax para otra cosa de la pagina y pasa que utilizo la misma pagina de backend.php para hacer las consultas. Entonces aunque la función para enviar los datos de este segundo ajax del que tenia la duda no se cumplen, utiliza las variables y arranca de todas formas y los inserta donde la primera función de ajax.

Comment: Había pensado en poner las declaraciones IF dentro de una función que llamaría el segundo ajax del que tenia la duda pero claro para hacerlo enviaría de todas formas una variable que declararía fuera de esta nueva función que crearía y entonces pasaría lo mismo.

No se si me habré explicado muy bien, ¿pero eso es porque no debería utilizar la misma pagina o hay alguna forma de que eso no suceda?

Answer (score 0):

yo lo aria asi

```
$get_dia_sel = $_GET['dia_id'];
  $get_dia_sel2 =$_GET['dia_id2'];

  if(isset($get_dia_sel)) {

      $link = mysqli_connect....;
      mysqli_select_db....;

      $query = "SELECT....";

      if($get_dia_selected == '0'){

         $query_contenido = "SELECT...."; 
         $query_count_contenido =   "SELECT ....";
      }

      $result_query = ....;
      $result_contenido = ....;

      $result_count_contenido = ....;
      $row_contador = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_count_contenido);
      $count_contenido = $row_contador['c'];

      if ($count_contenido < 8){

          foreach ($result_contenido as $row_contenido) { 
                  $var1= "<li><a><span>".$row_contenido['contenido']."</span><h5>".$row_contenido['nombre']."</h5></a></li>";
          }

          foreach ($result_query as $row_query) { 
            for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
                  $var2= "<li><a><span>".$row_query['contenido']."</span><h5>".$row_query['nombre']."</h5></a></li>";
          }
      } 
  header('Content-type: application/json');

   echo json_encode(array("var1"=>$var1,"var2"=>$var2));
 }

 if(isset($get_dia_sel2)) {.......(el patrón de contenido es el mismo).............}
```

ajax

```
var dia_em = $(this).val();
$('.form_input_dias').val(dia_em);

var dia_em2 = $('.form_input_dias').val();

$.ajax({ 
    url:"backend.php",  
    method:"GET",
    data:{dia_id:dia_em, dia_id2:dia_em2}, 
     datatype:"json", 
    success:function(data){ 
    var data_parse = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#bxslider1').html(data["var1"]); //es mas recomendable usar ids cuando se trata de javascript/jquery
        $('#bxslider2').html(data["var2"]); 

    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    },
});
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero eso no me ha servido. Aunque ya había probado algo muy parecido en que el array lo declaraba antes. Y los datos resultantes tu me los has sacado solo de la primera función y faltaría aun la segunda. Aunque he probado añadiéndola y tampoco.  Por cierto, si el encabezado ya está analizado application/json ya no es necesario analizarlo con JSON.parse.